# Syntax for Field Calculator in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, python-parser, error-000539

I'm migrating a legacy ModelBuilder tool that has a VB code block in it to ArcGIS Pro 2.9.
It's a straightforward issue:

The model runs a Calculate Field process.  If the field is not null, do nothing, else, add some text.  In this example, "crobj_py"

I got this to validate:

```
// Reclassify values to another value function 
Reclass(arg) { 
if (arg == null) 
   return "crsurv_ln"; 
 return arg; 
}
    
return Reclass($feature.FEATURE_CLASS_NAME);
```

However, when running the model it fails saying

```
ERROR 000539:   File "<expression>", line 1
   // Reclassify values to another value
    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax  Failed to execute (Calculate Field).
```

Can I not use `//` to comment code in the expression?

[image]

Comment: You appear to be mixing python with arcade. I would start there and decide which scripting language you want to use.

Comment: I'd prefer python.  But if I click on the name of the field I get "$feature." appended to it.  I can't type "!FieldName!" as that won't work and throws an error.

Comment: I should have said... My intent was to use Python but if I'm in Model Builder and I click on my  Calculate Field block, I can only seem to use Arcade.   Clicking on a field name to add it, even if "Python" is selected, the "$feature." is appended before the field name, and I can't manually just type "!FieldName!"    I changed the type to Arcade and it does run as expected, but I am curious why I can't access python in the tool when launched from model builder.

Comment: I've just verified using ArcPro 2.9 that you can indeed use python in a field calculate tool which is in a model. May be you have a corrupted install of ArcPro? Or try a blank new model and project and build up your model that way to see if it is working?

Comment: Agreed.  I can also use Python in a fresh model in Pro 2.9.   However, the model in question was a legacy model built in an older version of ArcMap and when I bring that into Pro, it only allows me to use Aracde.   No matter.  At this point, it's easier to just use Arcade.  I'll rebuild the model in Pro if I need to.  Thanks for verifying.